# CustomView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view

I want to display my own custom View in a GridView. I tried with this Code:

```
GridView gv= (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TerminGrid);
Cursor cr = db.rawQuery(DatenbankManager.GET_TERMINE, null);

ArrayAdapter<Termin> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Termin>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
gv.setAdapter(adapter);

for(cr.moveToFirst(); !cr.isAfterLast(); cr.moveToNext())
{
    String titel       = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Titel"));
    String datumString = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Datum"));

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    Date datum = null; try { datum = df.parse(datumString); } catch (ParseException e) { }    

    Termin t = new Termin(getActivity(), db, titel, datum);
    adapter.add(t);
}
```

But when I run this code only a few Strings are displayed in the GridView. Do I realy have to create my own GridViewAdapter for this? I thought this is a normal View and I can diplay it with the code above... This is my Class:

```
public class Termin extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener
{
    public static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.termin_item;

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private String titel;
    private Date datum;

    public Termin(Context c) 
    {
            super(c);
            this.context = c;
    }

    public Termin(Context c,  SQLiteDatabase db, String titel, Date datum) 
    {
            super(c);

            this.context = c;
            this.db = db;

            LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.termin_item, this, true);

            this.setTitel(titel);
            this.setDatum(datum);
    }
}
```

And the layout for the Items:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/PaddingBottom"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/PaddingHorizontal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/PaddingHorizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/PaddingTop" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Titel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/MarginTop"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Datum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/MarginTop"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Uhrzeit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

I only want to display these Items in my GridView. The point is that i think the items are ready to display but I can't call `GridView.addView(...)` direclty. The layout for the items is loaded in the Contructor and all TextView and so on are set in the get and set Methods. How can I display this items without creating an own ListAdapter - in my eyes a ListAdapter is needless and memory wastage.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I display this items without creating an own ListAdapter

You can't, the default adapters know how to bind data to a limited amount of the standard views(basically `TextViews`, `ImageViews`), it doesn't know how to handle your custom view.

> ... in my eyes a ListAdapter is needless and memory wastage.

Well your `GridView` requires an adapter and in that adapter you'll basically do what it normally does so there shouldn't be any problems. I don't understand why you're so against a custom adapter it's very easy to implement one.

Another approach would be to put the `titel` and `datum` variables into a `Map`(I don't know what you do with the database reference) and that `Map` in a `List`. That list will be used then with a `SimpleAdapter` along with a `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder` to manually bind the data. I would just go with creating the custom adapter it's a much more cleaner solution.